# Upgraded OpenSSL - How do I get Apache HTTPD to Use?

Tags: apache, ssl, rhel, sha256

I recently had a need to upgrade an old server.  The server fulfills a very specific purpose and as such has not been kept up to date.  With the recent push for SSL to utilize SHA256 I needed to upgrade a few packages.

**Short Background**

The server is RHEL3 (yes, that is correct).

I downloaded and built OpenSSL 0.9.8q and ensured it was the only instance of OpenSSL on the server (moving the old instance to a backup directory).  I then downloaded and built cURL 7.15.5 with the `./configure  --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl` - pointing the `with-ssl` to my new OpenSSL directory.

Once cURL was built I tested my connection to the resource that is requiring sha256 using cURL.  My connection test was successful using cURL.

**On to my problem and question**

I downloaded httpd 2.0.59 and built it with `--enable-ssl` and `--enable-so`, but my tests did not work.

I also tried to d/l & build httpd 2.0.63 but I was having trouble getting 2.0.63 working at all.  I then took the `mod_ssl` built from 2.0.63 and put it into the 2.0.59 directory...no luck either.

I feel I am missing some element that connects httpd to my newly installed OpenSSL.  What do I need to do to ensure `mod_ssl` is using my new version of OpenSSL on the server?

I understand I am quite a few releases behind with my httpd instances, but again, this is an old server with a specific purpose.  My only goal is to get it working with sha256, not buy a new server with the latest RHEL, etc.

Thank for any input/assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Running

```
./configure --help |grep ssl
```

gives

```
--with-ssl=DIR          SSL/TLS toolkit (OpenSSL)
```

So just like the curl build you could try adding that.

Assuming you are not going to do the sensible thing and upgrade the OS.